# Array subscripting syntax not working

Tags: objective-c

I have a XCode project targetting iOS 7, and I have this code:

```
NSMutableArray *subviews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];

....

UIView *test = subviews[Ø];
```

However, the compiler complains that fails to compile with the error "Use of undeclared identifier '0'.

This is the first time that I've tried to use this newer syntax for accessing arrays. I can't see anything wrong with it though. I've also searched the project settings to see if there was anything that I need to turn on, to no avail.

What have I missed.

Comment: please mark @MartinR's answer as the correct one

Comment: Pleas see my comment on his answer

Comment: Hmm, the down votes are a bit unfair. Yes, it was a silly mistake - I'd copied some code from a GitHub doc page though, so it could well happen to someone else....

Comment: I guess downvotes are due to poor quality question, and none are going to take benefit from this. If you read the compiler error, you could have solved it yourself, isn;t it :)

Comment: It's ironic then. Most of the time people rarely answer my questions. This time I get an answer and everyone downvotes it! I'll admit that it was a stupid mistake though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
UIView *test = subviews[Ø];
```

replace `Ø` ("LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH STROKE") by the digit `0` ...

Comment: You're right! Damn copy and paste! :) I have to wait 10 mins to accepts your answer - how silly's that??